# CMD is closing and doesn't let see the result (Java, running a .jar from .bat)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

So, I made my first little program, if you can call it a program. I exported it from eclipse as a .jar file, and I'm running it with a .bat file. I don't think the problem is there, but here is what I wrote in the .bat:

```
start java -jar apples.jar
```

What I did to solve the problem was:

```
System.out.println("Press any key and then enter to exit"); 
String end = in.next();
```

But even so, it just closes. Thanks. If you want the see all the code, say. But it's mainly a big ass menu to finally do a small operation.

Comment: Does it work when you run `java -jar apples.jar` directly from the command line?

Comment: cant understand issue

Comment: @assylias No. I mean, the solution. I can see the result I want there, but the "program" finishes right away when I set the last variable.

Comment: @Niks Tyagi What's happening is that when I place the last variable, I can't see the result. The window closes right away, even though when I run directly from the command line I can see it, but still finishes the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` command on Windows causes the `java.exe` process to start in its own window; that window gets closed immediately when the `java.exe` process ends.

So, you have two options:

1. Don't use the `start` command. Remove the `start` command from the beginning of the command line.
2. Add a 'pause' statement to your batch file.

Comment: Ok. Added "pause" and didn't do nothing. After that, added a number after pause and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `java -jar apples.jar` and

```
System.out.println("Press enter to exit"); 
String end = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

to make it only needed to enter to exit